# How do I open up this cable box, or remove it entirely?

Tags: coaxial-cable

[image: Cable Box]

I am trying to remove this cable box to get some work done on the walls in the backyard. I bought one of these tools:

Cable Terminator Tool LTT-7 GTT-7 For TV CATV Box https://a.co/d/6GB7gfT

However, it doesn't fit inside the hole. The box has been there since we moved in a few years ago. We get a cable connection through a box in the basement, so this one has no use.

Comment: insert nose pliers and twist

Comment: @Ruskes inside the inner part? The entire part is loose and can be twisted left or right with pliers, but it doesn't seem to unlock anything.

Comment: is the outer part of the lock threaded like a standard male coax end piece?  hard to tell from your picture.  i've used your tool on these before the little wings retract into the tool to allow you to push it into the inner part of the lock where the wings expand and allow you to unscrew.  is your tool too large diameter with the wings retracted to fit inside the lock piece?

Comment: these boxes are expensive so don't break it !  I bought a low voltage enclosure like this and it was ~$60

Comment: Worst case, you could use a screw extractor—the kind that have a fluted tapered shaft.

Comment: @FreshCodemonger Yes, the tool is larger in diameter than the piece. There's another larger attachment for this tool that I was able to use to get it open. It is mentioned below in this thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's quite a similarity to the tool linked in the question and the one I've posted, but the purposes of each appear to be different. If the posted tool doesn't fit, there's a chance that the one in my answer may be better suited.

It's been years since I've seen one of these. The connector lock is usually placed on a fitting at a pedestal or on the pole mount subscriber taps, preventing pilfering of service. In today's digital age, no usable signal is available at a subscriber tap anyway, making the lock nearly useless.

Your local cable company may have a technician with one of the correct tools in his truck or you can grab one from [Amazon:](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B06XDJBMZH)

[image: locking fitting removal tool in use]

[image: Tool in use]

Photos from linked site.

Amazon USA price $9.99, other sources may exist and prices will vary.

Note also, that one can use a left-hand drill bit of appropriate size to bore out the internal portion, causing it to spin free.

Comment: I think I see what the issue is now. Both products are similar, but these images show an attachment on the head of the tool that might fit the lock. Do you happen to know what that attachment might be?

Comment: The "attachment" is a release mechanism that retracts the locking pin at the end of the tool. It has to be retracted to be inserted into the security connector, then extended to engage the internal slot, allowing rotation for removal. The sleeve on the cover prevents the "brute force" method of applying locking pliers (aka ViseGrips™) to crush the security connector.

Comment: That attachment did the trick. I was able to fit it over the piece and unlock the box. Appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to contact the company that owns/installed the box and explain what you want to do. A previous owner probably authorized the installation for their service. Your existing company installed what they needed, with your permission, to supply you with their service. People switch back and forth now-a-days with different providers so the companies don't remove their facilities from your property. They are there by granted easments that don't go away with change in property ownership. So don't just go and remove, destroy the equipment. The companies can come back and file claims against you for distruction of their property.
If the company no longer services the area, then just pry the box off the wall with a crowbar and the anchors will pull out with the box.

Comment: It's unlikely that the local cable company will be concerned with "destruction" of an abandoned cable demark box on a house which has service provided from a different location, as noted in the question. I've responded to service calls resulting from entire subscriber taps in a pedestal being destroyed by the property owner with no penalty to the owner. A simple box on the wall may be forgotten and thereby ignored. I agree that contacting the company may provide the least expensive solution, but also a longer term (low priority) service call.

Comment: This was the initial idea but the company that installed this box (RCN) no longer operates in my area.

Comment: @lagops If the company no longer services the area, then just pry the box off the wall with a crowbar and the anchors will pull out with the box.

Comment: @fred_dot_u  We live in an underground area with Comcast, AT&T and a new company, Hot Wire. All have facilities on walls and all have notifed residents through the homeowners assoc.  not to remove any boxes not currently being used under penalty. So people need to check this out.

Comment: If the company no longer services the area, ask them who owns the box, the answer you want to hear is that you own it,  but It may have ben transferred to a different provider. if so ask them.